# Directive is not updating the view with async data, using controllerAs and bindToController

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, controller, directive

I'm having some trouble getting a directive to update my view.

In my controller I set the intial values for the attributes of the `<tiki-list>` directive. Then after, 2 seconds, I'm updating `vm.listObjectSelected` to test its async behaviour.

However, the view is not reflecting the update.

**Controller**:

```
    var listObject = [{"display":"display1", "value":"value1"}, {"display":"display2", "value":"value2"}, {"display":"display3", "value":"value3"}]

    vm.listObject = listObject
    vm.listObjectSelected = [{"display":"display1", "value":"value1"}]

    $timeout(function(){

        vm.listObjectSelected = [{"display":"display1", "value":"value1"}, {"display":"display3", "value":"value3"}]

    }, 2000)
```

**HTML**

```
<tiki-list max="" type="multi" list="editController.listObject" selected="editController.listObjectSelected"></tiki-list>
```

**Directive**

```
(function(){

    'use strict';

    angular.module("tiki").directive("tikiList", tikiList)

    function tikiList(helper){

        var directive = {

            restrict:"EA",
            scope:{

                list: "=", //the object to repeat over, this contains 2 array's
                retunObject: "=", //the array that is outputted
                selected: "=", //preselected values
                max: "=", //maximum range, other elements are greyed out, starts at 0
                title:"@title", //the title of this list
                type:"@type", //[single, multi]

            },
            templateUrl:"js/directive/list.html",
            link:link,
            bindToController: true,
            controllerAs:"vm",
            controller:controller

        }

        return directive

        function link(scope, el, attr, ctrl){

            scope.vm.onClick = onClick

            // preprocess the "list" if there is a "selected" attribute
            // the "selected" attribute is an object that contains the selected items
            // return a "selectedItems" array containing the indeces of matching display names
            // add the .active property to the "list" object to the correct indeces

            if(scope.vm.selected){

                var selectedItems = helper.isItemInList(helper.createArrayFromProperty(scope.vm.selected, "display"), helper.createArrayFromProperty(scope.vm.list, "display"))

                for(var i = 0; i < selectedItems.length; i++){

                    scope.vm.list[selectedItems[i]].active = true

                }

            }

            // add the property .disabled to the "list" if there is a max attribute
            // the property will be added to all indeces that exceed the max value

            if(scope.vm.max){

                for(var y = 0; y < scope.vm.list.length; y++){

                    if(y >= scope.vm.max){

                        scope.vm.list[y].disabled = true

                    }

                }

            }

            function onClick(index){

                // only allow items that are in range of the "max" attribute are allowed to be clicked

                if(!scope.vm.max || index < scope.vm.max){

                    if(scope.vm.type === "single"){

                        angular.forEach(scope.vm.list, function(val, key){

                            scope.vm.list[key].active = false

                        })

                        scope.vm.list[index].active = true

                    }

                    if(scope.vm.type === "multi"){

                        scope.vm.list[index].active = !scope.vm.list[index].active

                    }

                }

            }

            scope.vm.listing = scope.vm.list

        }


    }

    controller.$inject = [];

    function controller(){




    }


})()
```

**Directive template**

```
  <ul class="listOptions">
    <li class="listOptions-title" ng-class="{'show':title}">{{vm.title}}</li>
    <li ng-click="vm.onClick($index)" ng-class="{'active':list.active, 'disabled':list.disabled}" ng-repeat="list in vm.listing track by $index">{{list.display}}</li>
  </ul>
```

I think it has something to do with controllerAs but I can't wrap my head around it.

thx,

Comment: Why do you always use `scope.vm`? If you're using `controllerAs` in conjunction with `bindToController` you can directly access your isolated scope properties on the `this` object, e.g. `this.selected`. With the `bindToController` property of the directive definition all properties of your isolated scope are automatically are bound to the controller rather than to the scope. There is no need to use `scope.vm`.

Comment: I'm using scope.vm because i'm trying to follow this style guide: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#directives

Comment: What you do inside `$timeout` is outside angular digest cycle. You need to call `$scope.$digest()` inside `$timout` after `vm.listObjectSelected = ...`

Comment: Yes, it's correct that `$timeout` is outside the angular lifecycle since it's wrapped around setTimeout. However, as far as I understand it, `$timeout ` implicitly calls `$scope.$apply` so it will be kickstarted in the angular lifecycle again.

Comment: I think because in your **directive** `scope.vm.listing` and `scope.vm.list` will not point to the same reference when you set your controller `listObject` to the new Array. Therefore your `scope.vm.listing` will not be updated although`scope.vm.list` is updated. Just set your `ng-repeat` to use your `scope.vm.list` instead of `scope.vm.listing` and it should work. [Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/themyth92/jb8faxk6/)

Comment: @themyth92 thx for you answer, i tried it out and it didn't work though...

Comment: I misunderstand your `listObjectSelected` and `listObject` in your controller. You should use `$watch` to notice the change in `listObjectSelected`. [Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/themyth92/jb8faxk6/1/).

Comment: @themyth92, thx this is the solution... but why is the two-way databinding of the directive not working? Since i have set selected to "=" you would expect this to work?

Comment: Actually in your directive, if you notice, the `scope.vm.selected` got **change** when `vm.listObjectSelected` **change**. However, you dont have anything to **listen** to the **change**. You only have an `if-else` and this will be executed once the directive finish `compile` and execute `link` function. Then 2 seconds later how you notice the **change** when data in controller change. That's why I use `$watch` to listen to it and do whatever I want when the **change** happens.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason is that the Array is a reference type. When you change the data in service or at async step, the data point goes to a new location in memory, but the data in directive or controller doesn't change.

Instead of writing your function like this:

```
$timeout(function(){

    vm.listObjectSelected = [{"display":"display1", "value":"value1"}, {"display":"display3", "value":"value3"}]

}, 2000)
```

You should try doing it this way:

```
$(timeout(function(){vm.listObjectSelected.push({you need data here})},200)
```

or you can use a promise ,you can return a promise and get it in directive ,use

```
promise.then(function(){//let data = service.data again}
```

Hope this can help you.